# Keep a figure "on hold" after running a script

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have this Python code:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *

time=linspace(-pi,pi,10000)
ycos=cos(time)
ysin=sin(time)

plot(time,ycos)
plot(time,ysin)

show()
```

If I do all these steps via an Ipython terminal, I can keep the figure open and interact with it. However, if I run the script via `$python script.py` the figure opens and closes instantly.

How could I have the same behavior as the Ipython terminal but when run as a script?

Comment: I run this exact code and I can zoom, pan, etc, just fine. What is your default backend ?

Comment: I have no idea, I always used spyder IDE until now. How can I check? Spyder loads PyQt4 by default, since it cannot find PySide.

Comment: `import matplotlib; print matplotlib.get_backend()`

Comment: It's `Qt4Agg` then, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Works fine here, you might need to detail something more about your issue.

Comment: I have no idea how to detail it deeper. It just opens and closes at the end of the script. What behavior do you experience? The figure just stays open until you click or something/close figure?

Comment: You should have mentioned `Spyder` on your initial message, I never used it. I found a question that might interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713966/interactive-plotting-in-spyder-with-matplotlib, this http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=859 also seems interesting.

Comment: oh! no but spyder works like a charm, that's why I dont mention it. Because I'm trying to run the scripts without spyder or any IDE, directly on the terminal. thank tho!

Comment: I don't know then, I always use bare terminal and it just always worked for me so I never looked into this problem. You could mention your OS then, it might make a difference for someone that is aware of this issue.

Comment: I had this problem in the past, too. What I usually just did was adding a `raw_input()` after the last line, which waits until you hit enter on your keyboard. It's a bad workaround, but its useful :)

Comment: @mmgp: im on a linux mint 13 64bits.thanks tho! @David Zwicker:Oh! I was looking for that kind of command as a workaround! Thanks! I was actually looking at a matlab-like `pause()`, which is practically the same as this.

Comment: Why does `pylab.show()` return immediately on this system configuration ?

Comment: @vint-i-vuit: Apparently `show` can take a parameter `block`. What happens when you use `pylab.show(block=True)` ?

Comment: @mmgp: goddammit, that's it! Like a charm, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a more sensible answer after taking a quick look into the problem.

First, let us suppose that

```
from matplotlib import pylab
pylab.plot(range(10), range(10))
pylab.show()
```

does not "hold on" the plot, i.e., it is barely shown before the program ends. If that happens, then the call `pylab.show()` assumed you were running in interactive mode, so there is some other process going on that will continue executing after this function is called. Since this is not the case, Python exits and so does the plot display. Now, the first approach to solve this is forcing `pylab.show` to block by doing:

```
pylab.show(block=True)
```

Still, we don't know why `pylab.show` assumed you were running in interactive mode. To confirm its assumption, experiment running the following code

```
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.is_interactive()
```

if this prints True, then that means your default configuration is set to `interactive: True`. To check which configuration is that, do `print matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()` to find out the path to it. Open it and check the value for the `interactive` parameter.

Now, if you prefer to not modify the configuration I would suggest a different solution:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pylab

if matplotlib.is_interactive():
    pylab.ioff()
pylab.plot(range(10), range(10))
pylab.show()
```

so there is no situation where `matplotlib` thinks it has to render stuff before calling the `show` method. Lastly, the most horrible of these solutions would be the use of `pylab.pause` or equivalents:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
pylab.ion()  # Force interactive    
pylab.plot(range(10), range(10))
pylab.show() # This does not block
pylab.pause(2**31-1)
```

Comment: This is a PERFECT answer, thank you for everything, now apart from knowing what to do to get the behaviour I want, i also know WHY. To be honest I thought it was a bit weird that plots would show up without having the `show()` line in the script, but I just ignored it, the interactive mode is the key. +10 !

Comment: Came here after a while. Does this work also when using `pyplot`?