# Matplotlib figure window disappears when in interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive

I need to use interactive mode when plotting with matplotlib (it should be a script, not python or ipython console). But setting `plt.ion()` causes a strange bug (?). When I try to plot my figure (I don't think it really matters, what I do exactly, because in non-interactive mode it works perfectly fine) I don't see it - I get a blank grey window for split-second, which momentarily disappears and the programme exits.
If I explicitly add `plt.draw()` (and `plt.pause(1)` to see the result), I see that the figure appears as expected. If I do the same after modifications I want to do to the figure when it is visible, the figure changes. But the window still disappears after the pause is over.

I run it in Spyder with Qt4Agg as a backend under Ubuntu. Tried running the script from terminal as `python my_script.py`, the result is identical.

What could be the problem? How do I stop the figure from disappearing when in interactive mode?

**UPDATE**

Working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

x = np.linspace(1, 10)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.draw()
plt.pause(1)
```

If I run this code I see the sine plot for 1 second, then the window disappears.

**UPDATE 2**

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724654/1304161
If I set the run options in Spyder correctly, it works perfectly fine. Although running it in gnome-terminal doesn't work, I don't really need it. Hopefully, there won't be a problem with this when it becomes a part of a GUI app...

Comment: @Ffisegydd I am afraid that is not that easy... I will try to make a working example.

Comment: OK, no problem, updated the question (none taken :))

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I know about that :) Was just working on the answer. Good luck to you too!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724654/1304161

If I set the run options in Spyder correctly, it works perfectly fine. Although running it in gnome-terminal doesn't work, I don't really need it. Hopefully, there won't be a problem with this when it becomes a part of a GUI app. I will be back, if it will be a problem then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work by adding these two lines at the end:

```
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

So this program works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

x = np.linspace(1, 10)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.draw()
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To display multiple figures at different times, you can use `code.interact(local=locals())`, after `plt.show()` to pause the Python interpreter until a Ctrl-Z is pressed in the Python Shell:

```py
import code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Start pyplot's "interactive mode" which lets you run plt.show multiple times
plt.ion()

x = np.linspace(1, 10)
y = np.sin(x)

# PLOT #1 - displayed
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.draw()
plt.show()

# Wait for figure to be closed AND Ctrl-Z pressed in Python Shell
code.interact(local=locals())

print("Some more code can go here...")

# PLOT #2 - displayed
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

# Wait for figure to be closed AND Ctrl-Z pressed in Python Shell
code.interact(local=locals())
```